# Auto detection of changes with disconnected entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am making a simple editor on a web server that lets user change/add data to a single table stored on a MS SQL server.

I am using Entity Framework 6 to do this, and I am wondering how I should do to track the changes made to the entity model.

I would have hoped that I could load new data in the context, and have the context automatically diff against what's in the DB, and then call SaveChanges().

But from what I read online, it looks like I need to loop through all the data, and check myself what changed, so that I can then call `Context.Entry(myEntry).State = Added` or `Context.Entry(myEntry).State = Modified`

Is there no way for EF to automatically detect what's new, what's modified and what's unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend passing ViewModels or DTOs to the view, then map them back to the reloaded entity on a commit. EF will automatically only update values that change when setting values. Setting a value without changing the value will not trigger an update. (Where attaching an entity, and setting it's modified state will update *all* columns) Passing entities, while convenient, exposes more about your data structure than your UI may present, and can be tampered with before being sent back. Never trust anything coming back from the client. When serialized to a client, the data is no longer an entity, it is a JSON block of data. When sent back to the server, it isn't a tracked entity, it is a POCO with the entity's signature. No change tracking that EF entities can provide will apply on the client or survive serialization/deserialization.

For example:

Given a Child that has a name and birth date. We select a DTO to pass to the view. The view changes a name, we get the DTO back and copy *all* values, modified or otherwise back into the entity and call `SaveChanges()`

```
// For example, loading the child in the controller to pass to the view...
ChildDTO childDto = null;
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    childDto = context.Children
       .Select(x => new ChildDto
       {
           ChildId = x.ChildId,
           Name = x.Name,
           BirthDte = x.BirthDate
       }).Single(x => x.ChildId == 1);
}

// View updates just the name...
childDto.Name = "Luke";


// Example if the view passed DTO back to controller to update...
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var child = context.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 1);
    child.Name = childDto.Name;
    child.BirthDate = childDto.BirthDate;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the name changed and the birth date did not, the EF generated update statement would only update the Name. If the entity name was already "Luke", then no Update statement would be issued. You can verify this behavior with an SQL profiler to see if/when/what SQL EF sends to the database.

Automapper can help simplify this for getting the DTO back into the entity:

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Child, ChildDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<ChildDTO, Child>();
});
```

Then when reading, leverage `ProjectTo` instead of `Select`:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    childDto = context.Children
        .ProjectTo<ChildDTO>(mappingConfig)
        .Single(x => x.ChildId == 1);
}
```

... and when updating the entity:

```
using (var context = new TestDbContext())
{
    var child = context.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 1);
    var mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    mapper.Map(childDto, child); // copies values from DTO to the entity instance.
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

It's important to validate the DTO prior to copying values across to the Entity, whether doing it manually or with Automapper. Automapper config can also be set up to only copy over values that are expected/allowed to change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and outstanding answer!